# Monitor all newly spawned processes on a Linux machine

Tags: process, ps, strace

Sometimes a process comes and goes faster than I can `ps aux`, I tried `watch -d -n0.1 "ps aux | tail"` but again, that's restricted to 1/10th of a second. What I really want is to run a command and follow all new processes, one per line, as they spawn. Even processes that run fast. I know `strace` has abilities similar to this but I haven't been able to get it to do what I want.

`tl;dr` : is there a way to log all new processes?

I don't want to know much, no more than a line of `ps aux` would give me, for the current case I just have a process that's spawned by another and disappears, I want to be able to run it, but I don't know what the command would be. Even knowing new PIDs would be sufficient, since I could figure a script that would take these and run `ps | grep` on these and give me more info while the process is running (assuming hopefully the process is still around when `ps` gets going)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you want to know about those processes? If you can control who spawns the processes, `strace -feprocess $SHELL` will do.

If it's just an overview of their footprint, use process accounting (in the gnu acct package; use the lastcomm command), or higher-level tools like atop's logger mode. In the future, tools like [trace](http://lwn.net/Articles/415728/) and uprobes will be helpful to get detailed info out of the kernel.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the process is spawned either by gnome or X, or one of their lackey processes. I can't be sure though.

Comment: Go with `lastcomm` then.

Answer (score 1):

auditd?

http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl

Comment: I thought this was just for files? You can't use it on /proc either

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

[Snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) might be the right tool for your use case.

If you need simple logger and you are NOT looking for security/auditing solution, then Snoopy might be it.

Disclosure: Snoopy maintainer here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lastcomm`, but as my Kernel is not build with Process Accounting, my only option was `top` to find a process which permanently woke up my USB HDD. Finally I came to this command:

```
top -b -c -d 5 > /tmp/top.log
```

It executes `top` every 5 seconds (`-d 5`) with the full list of all processes (`-b`) and full command (`-c`) and writes it to the file /tmp/top.log (`>`).

After I saw the disk spinning I stopped the logging, checked all output in the current timeframe and finally [found the culprit](https://forums.unraid.net/bug-reports/stable-releases/683-usb-hdds-randomly-spin-up-but-status-stays-unchanged-r1091/?do=findComment&comment=11087).

`top` allows `-d 0`, which "[causes (nearly) continuous updates](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top)", but continous writing to a log file produces huge load, so be warned.

If you don't want to write to a drive, you could use `tmpfs` to create a ramdisk, so the log files is written to the RAM.

Comment: unlike audit, this yields entirely unpredictable results for short-running processes (and for this example purpose, is an insult to the amount of work spent on `blktrace` & `fanotify` interfaces)

Comment: Yes it will, but this was my only option as `lastcomm` failed because my linux kernel has not accounting enabled and maybe it helps other users as well.